# problem to automatically generate a glossary by XeLaTeX

Tags: glossaries

I want to generate a glossary at the end of a document automatically, but the following code did not work. In fact no glossary was created. I am using XeLaTeX to compile a tex file in Mac TexLive environment.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\include{glossary}

He has a \gls{computer}.

\appendix
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibtex}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The glossary.tex file contains:

```
\newglossaryentry{computer}
{
  name=computer,
  description={is a programmable machine that receives input, and provides output in a useful format}
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you tried using `input` instead of `include`? These are two diffrent ways of embedding a file as far as I know. Also you need to run `\makeglossaries` after you created the glossaryentries, thus the glossary.tex

Answer (score 5):

Try the glossaries package. The documentation is very good. You will have it already but see [glossaries](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) for a description. [This guide](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) is aimed at beginners and [the full user manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) explains more advanced usage. As the beginners' guide explains, the command you use to specify the target word depends on how you want it to appear in your text.

Comment: I tried the above code. It did not work for me. No glossary page is created at the end of the document. Any further help?

Comment: Did you run latex (or pdflatex or xelatex or lualatex) -> makeglossaries -> latex (or variant)?

Comment: I only run XeLaTeX on TexShop (Version 2.47). I do not run it on terminal. Should I run it on terminal?

Comment: No. Running it in TeXShop does the same thing. But did you run makeglossaries?

Comment: No. In the list of options to set the type of LaTeX command (BibTex,MakeIndex,LaTeX,XeLaTeX,etc), I did not find a command for "MakeGlosseries". How can I run makeglossaries?

Comment: You can run it from the command line. You can also create an engine to do it within TeXShop if one doesn't exist but that's a bit more work.

Comment: @Masood Also, TeXShop has - or did have - a makeglossaries engine. However, you may need to activate it by moving it from the Inactive engines directory into the Engines one. My knowledge of TeXShop is very out of date but if you find a file makeglossaries.engine in the subdirectory Engines/Inactive of the TeXShop directory in your Library directory (the one for your user - not one of the system-wide ones) then try moving it to Engines so that you have Engines/makeglossaries.engine. You may need to reopen the document or restart TeXShop for it to show up as active.